# Function That Always Returns the Next Integer in a Sequence

Tags: .net, vb.net, caching

I need top create a function that gets the next integer in the sequence of 1 to 60.  Each time the function is called, I need it to increment from what the last value was and return the next number as the result.  It also cannot return the same integer in 2 consecutive calls.  When the count gets to 60, the sequence needs to reset back to 1.  I would like to function to have no parameters.

I have created a function that does this using the cache to store the last value that was returned, but I am worried that with concurrent calls to the function that it might not work as I expect and 2 calls could get the same integer.

Is cache blocking the correct method to use in this instance or is there something other method I am not thinking about?

Also, stuck using .Net 3.5 and this is a web application.

---

I just wrote this function based on using SyncLock.  Any obvious problems with it that I don't see? I am using the Cache to save the last value that was returned.

```
   Private Shared Function GetNextNumber() As Integer
        Dim o As Integer
        Dim r As Integer

        If Not Cache("NextNumber") Is Nothing Then
            o = DirectCast(Cache("NextNumber"), Integer)
        Else
            Cache.Insert("NextNumber", 1, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Caching.CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable, Nothing)
        End If

        Dim lock As New Object

        SyncLock lock
            If o = 60 Then
                r = 1
            Else
                r = o + 1
            End If
            Cache.Insert("NextNumber", r, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Caching.CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable, Nothing)
        End SyncLock

        Return r
    End Function
```

Comment: Is this a `Shared` function? Could it be called concurrently from multiple threads. I could infer this from you concern but you don't say.

Comment: The `<ThreadStatic>` attribute solves this problem.

Comment: It could end up being called from multiple threads.  I am looking into the `<ThreadStatic>` attribute now.

Comment: Judging by the definition on MSDN, I don't think ThreadStatic is what we are looking for: A static field marked with ThreadStaticAttribute is not shared between threads. Each executing thread has a separate instance of the field, and independently sets and gets values for that field. **If the field is accessed on a different thread, it will contain a different value.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ASP.net Cache is thread safe, but it is possible that two threads access the same object at the same time.

I'd recomend looking at the "ConcurrentQueue(Of T) Class" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx

The Concurrent Queue will block calls until the original call has completed. In addition because its a stack every time you remove an item you simply push it back into the stack making a sequential loop.

ie:

```
Module Module1

Private _Stack As New Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue(Of Integer)

Sub main()

    For i As Integer = 1 To 60
        _Stack.Enqueue(i)
    Next

    Do While True
        Debug.WriteLine(GetNext())
    Loop

End Sub

Private Function GetNext() As Nullable(Of Integer)
    Dim result As Integer

    If _Stack.TryDequeue(result) Then

        _Stack.Enqueue(result)

    End If

    Return result

End Function
```

End Module

This is how I would do it in 3.5:

```
Module Module1

Private _Stack As New Queue(Of Integer)

Sub main()

    For i As Integer = 1 To 60
        _Stack.Enqueue(i)
    Next

    Do While True
        Debug.WriteLine(GetNext())
    Loop

End Sub

Private Function GetNext() As Nullable(Of Integer)
    Dim result As Integer

    SyncLock _Stack

        result = _Stack.Dequeue()

        _Stack.Enqueue(result)

    End SyncLock

    Return result

End Function
```

End Module

Comment: Sorry, I just edited the question to note that we are on .Net 3.5, so I don't think that class is available to use.

Comment: It isn't...You can use just normal Queue(of T) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c.aspx and wrap the _Stack.Dequeue in SyncLock http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3a86s51t(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: The SyncLock method might look like the way to go.  Hopefully I can test it today and let you know.

Comment: So far in our testing the synclock method is working without problems.

Answer (score 0):

In java I would use an AtomicInteger... Found some ports for [.Net](http://code.google.com/p/netconcurrent):

Java code snippet:

```
public class Sequence {
   private final AtomicInteger counter;
   Sequence(int max) {
     counter = new AtomicInteger(0); 
     this.max = max);
   }
   public int next() {
     counter.compareAndSet(max,0);
     return counter.getAndIncrement();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're implementing an `IEnumerator`.  [The MSDN article for that interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.aspx) is a good place to get started.  Regarding thread safety, the article states:

> The enumerator does not have exclusive access to the collection; therefore, enumerating through a collection is intrinsically not a thread-safe procedure. Even when a collection is synchronized, other threads can still modify the collection, which causes the enumerator to throw an exception. To guarantee thread safety during enumeration, you can either lock the collection during the entire enumeration or catch the exceptions resulting from changes made by other threads.

For an example of using locking to create a thread-safe `IEnumerator`, see [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/56575/Thread-safe-enumeration-in-C).

Now, does your thread-safety require that each thread use its own `IEnumerator` or that they share one?  I think the CodeProject article referenced is assuming the former.  The latter may be difficult because `MoveNext` and `Current` are, by design, separate operations.  So locking both atomically sounds like a design challenge.

Luckily, it looks like Jon Skeet has [taken up that challenge](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/10/23/iterating-atomically.aspx) :)

Comment: Did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: I am open to any solution that works.  This function will be used globally in our application, so it's needs to be reliable whether it's single thread or multithread.  It is an online application if that helps.

Comment: @NinjaBomb: It sounds like you want a thread-safe singleton for the object, then.  Not a separate object for each thread.  That is... If Thread1 asks for a number, it gets 1.  Then thread3 asks, and it gets 2.  Then Thread1 asks again, and it gets 3.  Thread2 asks, gets 4.  And so on.  In that case, the linked post in Jon Skeet's blog would be recommended.  The only difference is that, when reaching the end of the collection, you don't want to stop enumerating.  You want to reset to 1.